# Given joint density function, derive $\alpha$ and calculate maximum likelihood formula

Tags: maximum-likelihood, gradient-descent, joint-distribution

Given the join density function 
$$
f(X_1 = x_1, X_2 = x_2, X_3 = x_3) = \alpha\cdot exp[{\eta _1 x_1+ \eta _2x_2 + \eta_3x_3 - w_{12}x_1x_2- w_{13}x_1x_3- w_{23}x_2x_3]}
$$, where the parameter set $\theta$ is $\{\eta_1, \eta_2, \eta_3, w_{12}, w_{13}, w_{23}\}$, $\alpha$ is a normalizing factor of $\theta$ that guarantees the total probability to be 1, $exp[]$ denotes the power of $e$. 
The data set is $\hat X_1, \hat X_2, \hat X_3$ of size $N$ (3 columns, $N$ rows, $\hat X_i \geq 0\ , i = 1,2,3 )$.

How to derive the maximum log likelihood function $l(\theta)$ and its gradient $\nabla l(\theta)$. I'm already stuck in deriving an explicit expression of $\alpha$ using $\theta$.Thank you!

Comment: you don't need to find alfa to maximize that function, you already know that it is positive (probability always is) so just maximize the rest of the function

Comment: By the way, if your $x$ spans all over positive reals, then your distribution is ill defined.

Comment: @carlo Thank you so much for your help. I'm afraid that I didn't express my question clearly. $\alpha$ is actually an expression of $\theta$, not a constant. So when I calculate the derivative, I must include the derivative of $\alpha$ with respect to $\theta$. How should it be done then?

Comment: Yoona, please visit https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts to merge all your accounts.  This makes it possible for you to edit and comment on your posts.

Comment: Do you have any restrictions on the parameters such as $\eta_i<0$ ?  And is $X_i$ between 0 and $\infty$?  And maybe first looking at the bivariate problem (just using $X_1$ and $X_2$) would help clarify things.